# Selenium: unable to get textbox value

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to print the value inside the Quantity textbox (*i.e* 2) on the java console as this page is using Angular JS.[image]

```html
<input id="a0X63000000WSgtEAGQI" class="input-edit ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" maxlength="16" min="0" ng-blur="onDblClickQuantityInp(item.Id,item)" ng-keyup="onKeyUpQuantityInp(item.Id,item)" ng-model="item.Bsvp_Quantity__c" placeholder="0.00" valid-number="true" type="text">
```

How do I get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I did not anticipate that **getAttribute("value")** would get the value inside the textbox. I thought of using the variable instead because value was not inside the HTML tag & made no sense but then I went ahead & found out.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='watchtab']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/div/input"));

String value = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JavascriptExecutor`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/), like

```
if(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    String s = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).
     executeScript("return document.getElementById(\"a0X63000000WSgtEAGQI\")
     .getAttribute("value");                                  
    ");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You need to  `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;`

Comment: Good to note that since we don't want any Javascript to possibly modify our page which is being tested, it's better to do this work by Selenium itself.